# Want to delete all record as per id and then insert in laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5

I want to delete all record according to id and then insert record in same table,I tried many ways but can't find solution please help me.
Basically as per the document id i want to delete all document but it is not working.
Here is my controller code:

```
foreach ($receievers as $user) {
                   $this->shareRepo->deleteSharedDoc($resourceId);
               $this->shareRepo->saveshareSharedDoc($resourceId, $user->id,$this->getCurrentUser());
}
```

The repository code:

```
function saveSharedDoc($resourceId, $sharedWith, $resourceOwnerId){
        $shareDocs = new ShareDocs;
        $shareDocs->resource_id = $resourceId;
        $shareDocs->shared_with = $sharedWith;
        $shareDocs->user_id = $resourceOwnerId;
        $shareDocs->shared_on = $this->getCurrentDateTime();
        $shareDocs->token = str_random(20);
        $shareDocs->save();
        return $shareDocs->token;
    }
    function deleteSharedDoc($resourceId){

            $network = ShareDocs::where('resource_id','=',$resourceId);
            $result=$network->delete();

        return $result;

    }
```

Please help me out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's seems you're doing it correctly. But there are two things that you have to change.

1. You are calling to `saveshareSharedDoc` method within `foreach` loop to save data. but actual method name on your repo is `saveSharedDoc`. (there two "share" words on loop)
2. you can return deleted rows directly `return ShareDocs::where('resource_id', $resourceId)->delete();`